# Why I am getting multiplying values (duplicate rows) for MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

While executing MySQL querying I am getting multiple (Duplicate) values but In actual it should be one. In result it is displaying expected row equal to number of total rows present in table a.

```
SELECT a.* FROM `table1` a join `table2` b on (a.`synonyms`='Mmcs_0006');
```

or

```
SELECT a.* FROM `table1` a join `table2` b on (a.`synonyms`like'Mmcs_0006');
```

or

```
SELECT a.* FROM `table1` a, `table2` b where a.`synonyms`='Mmcs_0006';
```

To make sure that there is only one row I executed following query,

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.`synonyms`='Mmcs_0006';
```

Here result table displaying only one entry. (In actual it is one only).

What could be the reason? Because I have to execute this query many times.

Comment: I would recommend you to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-tables.html

Comment: 'Mmcs_0006' is a string. This is an odd thing to join on. Perhaps you meant \`Mmcs_0006\`

Answer (score 2):

you are not specifying anything to join in  table 2, therefor you are are joing against all rows in table 2 (outer join).  If table 1 and table 2 share a common key you would need to join on that, and then add a where clause to limit.

something like

```
 SELECT a.* 
   FROM `table1` a join `table2` b on a.id = b.fk_id      
   WHERE a.`synonyms`='Mmcs_0006';
```

where `fk_id` is a the reference to table 1 (a)

but also you don't appear to be using any values from table 2 (b). So not sure why you need to join / access it..

From comments, as opposed to joining, you can use an `IN` / `Subquery`) to limit you SELECT to only rows matched in table2 perhaps.

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM table1      
   WHERE synonyms IN (SELECT synonyms from table2)
   AND synonyms = 'Mmcs_0006';
```

Comment: SELECT a.* FROM `table1` a join `table2` b on a.`synonyms`=b.`synonyms` WHERE a.`synonyms`='Mmcs_0006'.   I executed this query but no rows found. Here  synonyms of table2  is subset of synonyms of  table1.

Comment: does Mmcs_0006 exist in b.synonyms?  ie does select * from table2 where synonyms='Mmcs_0006'  return any rows?   (also you are not using any information from table2.  what exactly are you looking for?)  Do you want all the information from table1 (a) if a synonym exists in table2 (b) ?

Comment: Yes, Mmcs_0006 exsist in both and I need all information from table1 if Mmcs_0006 match between both. there are around 25000 synonyms entries in table1 and table2 is having around 5000.

Comment: see edit. if the select works on table2, but not when you join them then something is wrong what type is the synonyms field in both tables? Do they each contain only 1 value or lists of values?